# Clone Git repository with Gradle before building using NDK

Tags: android, c++, git, gradle

I am porting a C++ application to Android. The project depends on some libraries. Instead of building these libraries manually, I would like to instruct Gradle to clone and build the libraries. Problem is, I do not have a lot of knowledge of Gradle yet.

I found [Grgit](http://ajoberstar.org/grgit/) to clone the repositories, for example for JsonCpp I have this task:

```
task cloneJsonCpp {
  File jsonCppDir = new File('cloneJsonCpp')
  if (!jsonCppDir.exists()) {
    org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit.clone(dir: jsonCppDir.absolutePath, uri: 'https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp.git')
  }
}
```

I want this task to be invoked before doing native build. I establish a relationship [like this](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/native-cant-specify-dependson-tasks-for-cpp-compilation-tasks/8700/2):

```
model {
  tasks.externalNativeBuildDebug {
    dependsOn cloneJsonCpp
  }
}
```

When Gradle is syncing, I get the error:

```
Gradle project cmake.path is .../cloneJsonCpp/CMakeLists.txt but that file doesn't exist
```

I guess that it is because the file is evaluated before launching any task, but I am wondering whether I can clone the repository before launching the C++ compilation?

Comment: You are calling `Grgit.clone(...)` in the configuration phase of the task, rather than the execution phase. Net result is clone will happen for every single gradle invocation, regardless of if the task executes or not. Move to a `doLast { ... }` closure or use the tasks from [gradle-git](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git)